# Django - TypeError - save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert'

Tags: python, django

Im new in Django and I can't figure out this error. Help please. It gave TypeError - save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert'. I tested the code below and they were able to save the new user registration but now it won't save anymore...

Here is part of the views.py that i think got some problem:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
    from django.contrib import messages
    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
    from . forms import UserRegisterForm, UserUpdateForm, ProfileUpdateForm

    def register(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            form.save(force_insert=False)
            messages.success(request, f'Thank you {username}! Your account has been created!')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()

    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form':form})
```

and the models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='profile_pics/default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.user)

    def save(self):
        super().save()

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300,300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)'
```

Comment: change `form.save(force_insert=False)` for `form.save()`

Answer (score 120, accepted):

When you are overriding model's save method in Django, you should also pass `*args` and `**kwargs` to overridden method. this code may work fine:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    img = Image.open(self.image.path)

    if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
        output_size = (300,300)
        img.thumbnail(output_size)
        img.save(self.image.path)'
```

Comment: thanks, it is work, but can you explain why it works?

Comment: @JuliarNasution - every function has a "signature", a pattern of arguments. If you override `save` with a new definition that doesn't take any arguments (except the implicit `self`), you get the reported error when it is passed an argument it is expected to handle, e.g. `force_insert`. The `*args, **kwargs` syntax says, "collect all positional args in the `args` list and all keyword args in the `kwargs` dict". Tnen they can be passed along via the `super` call to do their work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This work perfect. Got this in Corey ms Django blog project.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent explanation! @PaulBissex

Answer (score 19):

You've overridden the save method, but you haven't preserved its signature. Yo need to accept the same arguments as the original method, and pass them in when calling super.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save((*args, **kwargs)
    ...
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.

This will fix it:

Edit the super method in your *users/models.py* file:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super.save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: some reason only this worked for me , thanks

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to overload the built-in save, so that I could print to the console, to know when my local was saving vs my dev server. This helped!

Comment: FYI, my full code was `
    def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
        print("saving favorite")
        self.save_base(*args, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 0):

### Python 3 version

I was looking for this error on Google and found this topic. This code solved my problem in Python 3:

```py
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
            super().save(force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
```

- Tested with `Django 3.0` and `Python 3.8`.

[Django `models.Model` source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/db/models/base.py#L662).