# Error in python django when trying to save a user manually

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am experimenting some error when i try to create a new user manually in django

This is my code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

newuser = User()
newuser.username = request.data['username']
newuser.first_name = request.data['first_name']
newuser.last_name = request.data['last_name']
newuser.email = request.data['email']
newuser.is_active = True
newuser.set_password(request.data['password'])
newuser.full_clean()
newuser.save()
```

The code is able to insert correctly the user, I see the changes in my database, however the code breaks after saving the user with this

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 413, in create
obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
TypeError: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert'
```

I really can not figure out what the problem is

Comment: What version of django are you using?

Comment: Hi, Django version 2.1.7,

Comment: Why you are not using User.objects.create() function? you can create a dictionary with all the data you need and then pass it to this function.

Comment: @JuanMiGabarron - `create()` is a shortcut for the perfectly valid code the OP is using.

Answer (score 0):

Use this User instead

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model

Comment: Only makes a difference if a custom user model is used.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem adding this code

```
args = ()
kwargs = {}
newuser.save(*args,**kwargs)
```

I took the idea of this post
[Django - TypeError - save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52351756/django-typeerror-save-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-force-insert/52351829)

In fact I detected that all my forms are failing too, for example one of my forms

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name','last_name','username','email','password1','password2']
```

was working ok until today when it failed, so I needed to change it to

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)**

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name','last_name','username','email','password1','password2']
```

I do not know when this problem started, I mean in what django version.