# trying to createsuperuser on heroku but it throws me a typeError

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, heroku, typeerror

i tried this command to createsuperuser using this command

```
"heroku run python manage.py createsuperuser"
```

but it always throws me this error

```
Running python manage.py createsuperuser on ⬢ django-blog-web-app... up, run.4727 (Free)enter code here
Username (leave blank to use 'u10279'): ######################
Email address: #######################
Password:
Password (again):
'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 79, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 189, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 158, in create_superuser
    return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 141, in _create_user
    user.save(using=self._db)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 66, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 745, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 793, in save_base
    post_save.send(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 173, in send
    return [
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 174, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "/app/Users/signals.py", line 10, in create_profile
    Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 433, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
TypeError: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert'
```

i followed this [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Deployment) to deploy my project on heroku.com

tried very hard to find a solution to my issue on the internet didn't any

please help...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django - TypeError - save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force\_insert'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52351756/django-typeerror-save-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-force-insert)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that it shouldn't work for you locally either. If your models have overridden `save` method, please check if you're always passing *args and **kwargs to overridden method.

Note that the exception is raised in a signal, on line `Profile.objects.create(user=instance)`.