# save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert'

Tags: django

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import UserRegisterForm, UserUpdateForm, ProfileUpdateForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()         
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created. Log In to continue.')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```

This is the code when I run it I get an error. But that error shouldn't be there since I am not overriding the the save() method. please help.

Comment: Can you show your `UserRegisterForm`?

Answer (score 0):

try to get each form input one by one and then save the form. for example:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        data = YourModelName()
        data.input1 = form.cleaned_data['input1']
        data.input2 = form.cleaned_data['input2']
        # ... 
        form.save()         
        messages.success(request, 'Your account created. You can now Login.')
        return redirect('login')
else:
    form = UserRegisterForm()
return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Why? OP has a form, why would the OP need to do that?

Comment: sometimes its better to do this way according to my experiences

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that you are doing Corey Schafer's Django tutorial. If so, other users have had the same problem, which is discussed here:

[Django - TypeError - save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52351756/django-typeerror-save-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-force-insert)

The issue lies in overriding the save method in your Profile model