# TypeError in Django: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert'

Tags: python, django

It's about a blog project in a course, that as it seems it works for many other students, but not for me. So I would like to see what is going wrong with my code. The error message is:

```
TypeError at /register/
save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert'
```

The relative with the issue files are the following:

users/***views.py:*** (in the 4th raw of *register* function is the save() method that fails)

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import UserRegisterForm, UserUpdateForm, ProfileUpdateForm


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f"Your account has been created! You are now able to log in")
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/register.html', {'form': form})


@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)

        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f"Your account has been updated!")
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/profile.html', context)
```

users/***models.py:***

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username} Profile"

    def save(self):
        super().save()

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

and there are also a users/***forms.py:***

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile


class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']


class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']


class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image']
```

... a users/***signals.py:***

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

... and lastly in users/***app.py*** are imported signals:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'users'

    def ready(self):
        import users.signals
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52351756/django-typeerror-save-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-force-insert) should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When overriding `save` method in Django the signature should be kept as well.

Change to `def save(self, *args, **kwargs)`:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you! I had seen answers like the one I was shown (not that one), but I didn't understand in my code the connection between the Profiles save() method in models.py, and the form.save() of register function in the views.py.