# Error occur when to register Django apps : save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert'

Tags: python, django

When I try to register, it show a error: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert'

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to login!')
            return redirect('users-login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: could you to give us you error message?)

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52351756/django-typeerror-save-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-force-insert

Comment: Probably the error is in the Model... share the model code

Comment: Now I got it,  noticed there about *args and **kwargs